# Escape Root Layout Svelte Sveltekit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

According to the new routing system you can now group routes and have specific layout files in each group. These files inherit for their parent layout files. You can omit this, by using `layout@.svelte`.

However in want to omit the root layout file at `src/routes/layout.svelte`. Is there a way to do that?

(Here is the guide: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing#advanced-layouts)

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve that by using groups. Wrap all files from routes into a folder named “(app)”  and other routes you don’t want to use the default layout in another group. For example, If you want to have a layout for ‘/’ and ‘/blog’ but don’t use it on ‘/login’ then you could use the following folder structure:

```
src/routes/
├ (app)/
│ ├ blog/
│ │ └ +page.svelte
│ ├ +page.svelte
│ └ +layout.svelte
└ (login)/
   ├ login/
   │ └ +page.svelte
   └ +layout.svelte
```

Comment: [Advanced layout docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing#advanced-layouts) show a similar grouping example with a layout file at the top-level. It's not clear if grouping will still "escape" the ungrouped root layout under that condition.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

Just make the root layout empty (i.e. it only contains `<slot />`).

Comment: I assumed so... If I do that, how do I style the index page (`src/routes/+page.svelte`)?

Comment: Just put whatever you need into the page file itself if it is specific to that one page. Layouts are simply for shared code and styling, everything that is more specific should be handled by the pages themselves.